# How to assign chdir to a variable in .bat?

Tags: bash, windows-xp, batch-file, relative-path

I'm trying to translate a bash script into a .bat script.  The specific line I'm tripping over is this:

```
X=`pwd`
```

What is the .bat equivalent?

I need to take the directory that the script is currently running in as a variable so I can use a generic relative path to find files in the directory.  I'm running on Windows-XP in the command prompt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current directory is available in the pseudo-variable `%cd%`. So:

```
set X=%cd%
```

stores it in a variable named X.

Comment: You can also use `chdir`. Storing it into variable might be a bit different: `for /f %%a in ('chdir') do set pwd=%%a `